# SilverStripe running BuildTasks error via CronJob

Tags: php, cron, silverstripe

I'm working on running tasks via CronJob in SilverStripe 3.1.

I tested with command line, everything works fine.

But via Cron job, it always gives the following message:

> Please specify an argument to cli-script.php/sake. For more information, visit http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/commandline**"

I have read the docs but I still have no idea.

My cron job command:

```
/my_site_path/framework/sake dev/tasks/SendNewsLetter >> /my_site_path/newsletter.log 2>&1
```

I created a `SendNewsLetter` task which is extended from `BuildTask`.

I tried it in the browser and command line, it all seems to work with no problem. However, I haven't been able to get it working with cron job.

Comment: explain it more clear

Comment: I don't know SilverStripe, but I imagine it's cron job, not corn job.

Comment: Check job status in crontab using `crontab -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing it this way instead:

`php-cli -q /my_site_path/framework/cli-script.php dev/tasks/SendNewsLetter >> /my_site_path/newsletter.log 2>&1`